# how to configure the powershell version used by the package manager console in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget-package

I'm on Windows 11 Pro and I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 Version 17.2.5.
The package manager console is using Powershell version 5 and I have version 7 installed on my computer, is is possible to change the version used (for version 7) ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the same thing.

There is an Options panel for the Terminal in VS2022, but I haven't been able to figure out what needs to be changed in there to support a different version of PowerShell.

As a stop-gap measure until you find the answer, there is a PowerShell Tools (trial) in the Visual Studio Marketplace (I'm not affiliated) that will add support for multiple versions of PowerShell into the Terminal Window along with other enhanced behaviors.  At this point I don't know what the features difference is between the free/pro versions. Perhaps it will provide a hint for you on how to accomplish the conversion.

I'm looking forward to hearing your solution to the problem.